# adding ang removing row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a grid array of objects and it has default data from the database , now on the front end the data are being displayed on the table/grid and user can add row and delete row , when I add a row I only want to insert an empty object.

my issue is when I add a row duplicate ids are existing and when I delete only just a single row sometimes multiple rows are being deleted

What seem to be the issue of my implementation ? how do I delete and add rows without compromising the ids ? Thanks.

[image]

#grid data - from the database

```
gridTableData [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "demos": "21 Est. Pop",
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "demos": "Households",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "demos": "Avg HH Inc",
    },
]
```

#add and delete row code

```
 deleteRow(id: number) {
    const filteredDemographics = this.gridTableData.filter(s => s.id !== id);
 this.gridTableData = [...filteredDemographics];

  }

  addRow() {
    this.gridTableData.push({id:this.gridTableData.length});
    console.log("this.gridTableData" , this.gridTableData)
  }
```

#html

```
  <tbody *ngIf="gridTableData.length > 0">
                <tr *ngFor="let row of gridTableData;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'row-is-editing':isRowEditing(i)}">
                    <td>
                        <button *ngIf="checkIfExistsOnDefaultGrid(row) === false" class="material-icons-outlined" mat-icon-button color="error"
                            (click)="deleteRow(row.id)">
                            <mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Can you show the html? Because on the deleteRow you aren't changing anything on the gridTableDate, filter doesnt modify the original array. If you want to modifiy. I would recommend using  findIndexOf and Splice.

Comment: what do you want to see on the html Sir ?

Comment: I have added the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding with the row length and removing by index you might get some weird cases.

For example, if you add two entries in your snippet, you will have 2 rows with ID 5. Therefore, when you filter/delete, you would remove two entries.

If you want change the order, always use the index to remove or add.

If you want to use ID, make sure the ID will always be unique.

Here is a possible solution making the ID random
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pebbqb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: do you have some sample code?

Comment: added a snippet, but wont do the full solution. Please try a little yourself.

Comment: I already have provided the sample array of object to delete and remove an item.